# Is there any way to control per-device audio balance?

Tags: audio, google-pixel, android-12, equalizer

Device: Android 12, Pixel 6 Pro

I recently got a new Pixel 6 Pro and loved it so far, but the earpiece speaker seemed a little quiet to me, so i went into Accessibility settings and changed the audio balance.

Problematically, this also alters balance for Bluetooth headphones, Android Auto, ...

Is there any way through an app or natively that allows me to control balance just for my **phone's** speakers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution! With **[Wavelet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pittvandewitt.wavelet)** on Legacy Mode, you can control EQ, balance, and limiter per device.

Works flawlessly and only affect the phone's speakers!